# Best notation for instantiating an empty array?

Tags: java, arrays

To instantiate an empty array, which one of these two notations is the best:

1. `Object[] emptyArray = new Object[] {};`
2. `Object[] emptyArray = new Object[0];`

Are they exactly the same for the compiler? Does one appear clearer than the other?

*I am just asking out of curiosity: I am well aware it will have no impact on my program*

Comment: The second one lets you gain two precious bytes and its intent is probably clearer.

Comment: why do you need empty array?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov There are many legitimate cases where you start with an empty array that grows later.

Comment: second one is clearer :D

Comment: To avoid NPE... Such as the ``File[] listFiles()`` method for instance.

Comment: avoiding NPE can also be done with yoda conditions!

Comment: @Stefan But then you must have a test instead of just iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are they exactly the same for the compiler?

Yes. They both result in the same bytecode:

```
Object[] emptyArray = new Object[] {};

   0: iconst_0
   1: anewarray     #3                  // class java/lang/Object
   4: astore_1

Object[] emptyArray1 = new Object[0];

   5: iconst_0
   6: anewarray     #3                  // class java/lang/Object
   9: astore_2

  10: return
```

> Does one appear clearer than the other?

That is probably off-topic on SO, since it can lead to endless discussions :)

I would say `new Object[0];` is easier to read, but others may object.